# Joining two strings so that their common suffix and prefix are merged

Tags: regex, string, perl, concatenation

I have two words:

```
AGCGCGATAGC
       ^^^^
TAGCTATATATA
^^^^
```

The second word has `TAGC` is common with the first word. So I would like to have the result be:

```
AGCGCGATAGCTATATATA
       ^^^^
```

Is there any Perl function which combines these words? Using concatenation may result in repetition:

```
AGCGCGATAGCTAGCTATATATA
       ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: There isn't a built in function to do this. You'll have to write your own.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=484593

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this is to join the strings together with a character not in your alphabet:

```
my $s1 = 'AGCGCGATAGC';
my $s2 = 'TAGCTATATATA';
$_ = "${s1}_$s2"
```

Then match and replace the longest possible common string on each side of the separator:

```
s/([ACGT]*)_\1/$1/
```

Comment: $_ = "$s1_$s2" should be $_ = "${s1}_$s2" (to avoid the error) and [ACGT]+ should be [ACGT]* (to deal with inputs that have no common sub string).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Thank you. That’s what I get for not testing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use construct like this:

```
my $txt = 'AGCGCGATAGCD';
my $txt2 = 'TAGCTATATATA';
print "$txt\0$txt2" =~ /(.*)(.+)\x{0}\2(.+)/ ? "$1$2$3" : "$txt$txt2";
```